Issue with Apple sign in flutter
I'm trying to add Sign In with Apple to my Flutter app using the sign_in_with_apple: ^6.1.1 package. Here's what I've done so far:
main.dart
SignInWithAppleButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    try {
      final AuthorizationCredentialAppleID credential =
          await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error during Apple Sign-In: ${error}");
    }
  },
),

ios/Runner/Info.plist
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>com.domainname.travelbalance</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>

I've also set up the "Sign In with Apple" identifier in my Apple Developer account, recreated the provisioning profile and certificate, and added everything to Codemagic. And checked it on the real device.
I'am working on windows.
However, when I press the Sign In button, I immediately get the following error:
The Operation couldn't be completed (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError error 1000.)
The error occurs before the sign-in process even starts. Has anyone encountered this issue before or knows how to resolve it?

what is your app bundle ID registered at apple? also, In Xcode, go to your target's "Signing & Capabilities" tab and check if "Sign In with Apple" capability is added.

there should be a tag on your info.plist like:
CFBundleIdentifier
$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

The problem is, im developing under windows and visual studio code and building it to apple via codemagic. My bundle app Id is com.domainname.travelbalance, i have also the tag that u mentioned in my info.plist

I’m wondering what the “Sign in with Apple” option checked in Xcode actually does. Does it create a file or add something to existing files? Is it possible to recreate the steps in Visual Studio Code on Windows?
